# Add 20 minutes in string time and populate it in the textbox or alert it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a time string populated in select/list control e.g 05:40 I want to add 20 minutes in it and populate in textbox everytime when list value get changes in jquery or javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#starttimeList").change(function() {
var selectVal = $('#starttimeList').val();
    ////// HERE I WANT MY CODE AS selectVal is getting value of select control e.g. 05:40 and entTime is my textbox where I want the time added with 20 minutes.
$("#endTime").val(selectVal);

 });
});
```

Comment: To double check, you want to "watch" the `#starttimeList` element and whenever it is changed update another element (`#endTime`) to be 20 minutes ahead? What format should the `#endTime` time be displayed in?

Comment: #endtime is a textbox where I want to display the changed time (added with 20 minutes), when I convert the starttimeList value into date using javascript data object it says invalid time, If I could change the 05:40 to proper date and time then I might add 20 minutes in it but still did'nt get through with.

Comment: starttimeList is an HTML select control which is populated with time slots e.g 05:00, 05:20, 05:40 etc...

Comment: The JavaScript `Date` type represents exactly that, a date. If your `starttimeList` value is something like `05:40` how is the JavaScript interpreter supposed to convert that to a full date? 5:40 today? Yesterday? It's a more fundamental problem. You can construct a full date pulling the hours and minutes from the input and the rest from the current date, and then use that to compute an end time.

Comment: Is there any other way to add 20 minutes in the time without converting into date object. as my need is to just show 20 minutes added value in the text box when user selects from the list

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If time is in the format hh:mm, you can use a simple function to convert it to minutes, add more minutes, then convert it back to hh:mm again:

```
function addMinutes(time/*"hh:mm"*/, minsToAdd/*"N"*/) {
  function z(n){
    return (n<10? '0':'') + n;
  }
  var bits = time.split(':');
  var mins = bits[0]*60 + (+bits[1]) + (+minsToAdd);

  return z(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + z(mins%60);  
}  

addMinutes('05:40', '20');  // '06:00'
addMinutes('23:50', 20);    // '00:10'
addMinutes('00:00', '120'); // '02:00'
```

The minutes to add can be a number or string.

If you need to allow for daylight saving, using a date object may make life easier.

Comment: Thanks for this function. No momentjs required. Cheers!