# Add prev and next hour to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array with hours:

```
var hours = ['12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00'];
```

How can i add for this previous and next hours with 30 minutes? I would like receive:

```
var hours = ['11:30:00', '12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00', '13:30:00'];
```

How is the best way for this? I can use jQuery.

This is only example, i would like add prev and next for each array. I have also for example:

```
var hours2 = ['14:00:00', '14:30:00', '15:00:00', '15:30:00'];
var hours3 = ['11:00:00', '11:30:00'];
```

so i dont know values in array - i must check first and add prev and check last and add next.

Comment: If you plan on doing a lot of work with days/dates/times I would recommend adopting a library such as [moment](http://momentjs.com/) which will save you hours of headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var added = addTime(['12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00'])

    // -> ["11:30:00", "12:00:00", "12:30:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00"] 

function addTime(hours) {

  var t = ':30:00'

  // add:
  hours.slice(0).forEach(function(hour) {
    var h = parseInt(hour.split(':')[0], 10)
    hours.push(h-1+t, h+t)
  })

  // strip dups and sort:
  return hours.filter(function(elem, idx, arr){ 
    return arr.indexOf(elem) >= idx
  }).sort()
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9jKfA/

Comment: very, very thanks, but i have one issue. http://jsfiddle.net/9jKfA/1/ How is the best way in your script add 0 after single hour? Should be 01, 02, ... 08, 09 instead of 1, 2, ..., 8, 9

Comment: @user3033575 http://jsfiddle.net/m9BhX/ Create a zero method and adjust the sorting to cater for leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the elements to the back and sort it:

```
var hours = ['12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00'];
hours.push('11:30:00')
hours.push('13:30:00')
hours.sort()
// ["11:30:00", "12:00:00", "12:30:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00"]
```

Comment: this assumes the hours would be hard coded rather than based on the values already in the array, which may be what the OP wants, only the OP can tell :P

Comment: @jbabey Yeah there wasn't much information to go on in the question, hopefully this can give them a start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to prepend and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to append values to the array.

```
var hours = ['12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00'];
hours.unshift('11:30:00'); //['11:30:00','12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00'];
hours.push('13:30:00'); //['11:30:00','12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00', '13.30.00'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addMinutes(time, minsToAdd) {
    function z(n){ return (n<10? '0':'') + n;};
    var bits = time.split(':');
    var mins = bits[0]*60 + +bits[1] + +minsToAdd;
    var secs = bits[2];

    return z(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + z(mins%60) + ':' +secs;  
}

var hours = ['12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00'];

hours.unshift(addMinutes(hours[0], -30));
hours.push(addMinutes(hours[hours.length-1],30));
```

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338960/add-20-minutes-in-string-time-and-populate-it-in-the-textbox-or-alert-it). Displays 09 rather than 9...

var hours = ['09:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00']; --> 08:30:00,09:00:00,12:30:00,13:00:00,13:30:00