# How to change value of an input with buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in which I want the user to be able to set the value in 15 minute increments with the use of two buttons.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label " for="time">Authorisation Duration</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" value="00:00">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">+ 15 Minutes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">- 15 Minutes</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am wondering how to go about making it change the value according to which button is pressed. Also, how to I make sure it does not go into the negative.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: do you know about javascript ?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:javascript], but you haven't included any in the question … so try reading an introductory JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: (0) use a variable to store the number of 15-minute blocks allocated. (1) When the + button is pressed, increment this variable, then display the allocated time. (2) When the - button is pressed, check that the variable is greater than 0, if it is, decrement the variable and again, display the allocated time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```js
     $(function()
     {
      $(".btn-inc").click(function(){
       var v = $(this).data("val");
       $("#time").val(addMinutes($("#time").val(), v));
       
      });
      /*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338960/add-20-minutes-in-string-time-and-populate-it-in-the-textbox-or-alert-it*/
      function addMinutes(time/*"hh:mm"*/, minsToAdd/*"N"*/) {
       function z(n){
        return (n<10? '0':'') + n;
       }
       var bits = time.split(':');
       var mins = bits[0]*60 + (+bits[1]) + parseInt(minsToAdd);
       if(mins < 0) return time;
       return z(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + z(mins%60);  
      }
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label " for="time">Authorisation Duration</label>
     <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
       <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" value="00:00">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn-inc btn btn-info" data-val="15" type="button">+ 15 Minutes</button>
       <button class="btn-inc btn btn-danger" data-val="-15" type="button">- 15 Minutes</button>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried this but it didn't work. Is there something I am forgetting to do?

Comment: @SineBurridge There was one mistake - missed one bracket. Now it works

Answer (score 1):

**An example** with native functions ( `stepUp()` & `stepDown()` ):

```js
function incr() {
    document.getElementById("myTime").stepUp(15);
}
  
  function decr() {
    document.getElementById("myTime").stepDown(15);
}
```

```html
Time: <input type="time" id="myTime" value="16:32:55">

<p>Click the button to increment the value of the time field by 10 minutes (each time you click).</p>

<button onclick="incr()">+ 15</button>
  <button onclick="decr()">- 15</button>
```

---

**An example** ( with jQuery ) - integers:

```js
// Set counter default to zero
var counter = 0

// Display total
$("#counter").text(counter);

// When button is clicked
$("#add").click(function(){
  //Add 10 to counter
  counter = counter + 15;
 // Display total
 $("#counter").text(counter);
});


//Subtract
$("#subtract").click(function(){
  counter = counter - 15;
  $("#counter").text(counter);
});


// Reset
$("#reset").click(function(){
  counter = 0;
  $("#counter").text(counter);
});
```

```css
body{
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.button_group{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em; 
  font-weight: 300;
 border: 0;
 padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
 width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);  
  -webkit-transition:.2s;  
}
button:nth-child(2){
 margin: 0.5em;
}
button:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
button:active{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#add:active{
   -webkit-transform:translateY(-1em);    
}
#subtract:active{
   -webkit-transform:translateY(1em);    
}
#counter{
 font-size: 3em;
 text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
<div class="button_group">
 <button id="subtract">- 15</button>
 <button id="reset">Reset</button>
 <button id="add">+ 15</button>
</div>
```

Sources:

- [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/number-increment-buttons/)
- [Good example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/buttons-minus-and-plus-in-input) ( with Bootstrap & jQuery )
- [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/puJ6G/)

Comment: That adds and subtracts `10` to an integer. The question is asking about adding and subtracting *15 minutes* from a *time* which is expressed in hours and minutes.

Comment: @Quentin Thank for your comment. I corrected my mistake

Comment: It still deals in integers instead of times.

Comment: The native stepUp is Not supported from IE/Edge

Answer (score 0):

You can use native [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) `time` input:

```
<input type="time" step="900">
```

Try it:

```html
<input type="time" step="900">
```

The disadvantage is that is bad supported on Firefox and Safari so you can use this as alternative:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5">
<input type="range" min="0" max="15" step="5">
```

Comment: The question is dealing with time stamps, not integers.